# Is setTimeout located somewhere besides window?

Tags: javascript, html

The reason I ask is b.c. of the strange title for the MDN entry found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope

I'm trying to understand why it is not listed under the window object?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope

Comment: right but what gives with the weird title? you know String.slice

Comment: Because the function is part of the `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` mixin?

Comment: @brannonteer you can blame WHATWG for the verbose title: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#windoworworkerglobalscope-mixin

Comment: haha what it WHATWG?  What is the HTML living standard ?  All I use on the web is MDN ( Mozilla Developer Network ) ... I'm told it is legit.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browser environments have a `window` object that corresponds to the global scope.  Currently the various worker environments (Web, Shared, and Service) are good examples of these types of environments.

`WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` defines a common set of methods shared by all browser global scopes.  `Window` and `WorkerGlobalScope` define additional functionality on top of these methods.

This means, for instance, that you an access `setTimeout` from any browser JS environment but that `open` is only available in a window global scope and `importScripts` only in a worker environment.

Comment: any browser JS environment?  what browser does not have window?

Comment: "What do you call a browser without a window?"  Headless...  Sorry.  In seriousness, the point is that the introduction of web workers created a new type of global JS environment in the web browser that is not synonymous with window.